# Java for android Shared Database over LAN

Tags: java, android, database, lan

Hello i've been coding an app (client/server) over my LAN in Visual Studio 2012 using this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/A-Complete-TCP-Server-Client-Communication-and-RMI#ScsServerside as the base for my communication between the client and the server.

Now i started looking over on android development and eclipse and i was wondering if there was something similar to this framework on java? if not maybe someone could point me out on a way of calling methods over LAN and if possible without using the hole webservice on tomcat thing :p i cant really understand how that is working and since i intend to sell the app i dont know what implications using those components brings.. Whereas this framework i was working on didn't need anything.. it simply runs the application (server) with a service on the ipaddress of the machine on a open port ant that it.. Any help would be gratefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some more information to your question would be useful. For example: which kind of call are you *accepting* on your server? Or, in other terms, what protocol are you using? Just plain old HTTP? RESTful HTTP? FTP? SSH? What?

Anyway, most likely you do not need any third-party framework to create your own Android client. Android and Java already supply you with a HTTP library and a HTTP client that can be used to communicate with a HTTP server. Just browse the docu.

If you have to use a different protocol, most likely you can find a Java client/library that you can use in your project. Java has the largest library of ready-to-use components so it is usually quite easy to find something that can solve your problem.

Comment: Actually i looked into Java RMI and it's just what i was looking but thanks anyway ^^